# Wait to load html until a referenced js value loads from an async process?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, algolia, instantsearch

I am loading the value of a field of a document in my Firestore database via the following process:

```
let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
this.afs.collection("people").doc(currentUser.uid).get().subscribe( opportunities => {
 this.items = opportunities.get("following");
});
```

And then I'm using this.items to filter through my instantsearch data loaded in my html. I do this by defining the following config in the js code (note that I am referencing this.items as filter.

```
   this.config = {
        ...environment.algolia,
        indexName: 'test',
        searchParameters: {
            disjunctiveFacetsRefinements: {
            poster: this.items
        }
        },
        routing: {
          router: historyRouter(),
          stateMapping: {
            stateToRoute({query, page}) {
              return {
                query: query,
                page: page
              };
            },
            routeToState({query, page}) {
              return {
                query: query,
                page: page
              };
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Then in my html, I am referencing this config object as so:

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="config">
```

But the problem is that the html is loading this config file before my process for defining this.items successfully completes. I get that this is because it's an async process pulling from my database, but I cannot figure out how to resolve it. I tried adding the declaration of this.config into my opportunities => {} part of the code so that it happens after I get the this.items value; however, the html still loads and then it fails because config hasn't been defined yet. What is a good approach for solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend resolving the configuration with the async pipe.

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="config | async">
```

This will require making `this.config` an observable, I'd recommend the BehaviorSubject: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html

```
private readonly config: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

# ...

ngOnInit() {
    let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.afs.collection("people").doc(currentUser.uid).get()
        .subscribe(opportunities => {
            let items = opportunities.get("following");
            let config = {
                ...environment.algolia,
                indexName: 'test',
                searchParameters: {
                    disjunctiveFacetsRefinements: {
                        poster: items
                    }
                },
                routing: {
                    router: historyRouter(),
                    stateMapping: {
                        stateToRoute({ query, page }) {
                            return {
                                query: query,
                                page: page
                            };
                        },
                        routeToState({ query, page }) {
                            return {
                                query: query,
                                page: page
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            this.config.next(config);
        });
}
```

Comment: what exactly does this.config.next(config) mean?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how'd you handle it. this.config.next(<value>) is setting the value of the behavior subject, which is an observable. I'd recommend reading about observables and rxjs if you'll be doing heavy angular development.

Comment: for demonstration prupose and because @JohnD doesn't know what is your config model he put `any` as type. but it is highly recommended to strong type your observable with interface. Otherwise you loose the compilation type checking

Comment: If I change `new BehaviorSubject(undefined)` from "undefined" to "{}" it works, however it gets me back to where I started. The `<ais-instantsearch [config]="config | async">` line is still loading config as {} (and thus errors) instead of after it has been updated with the filtering. Any ideas here much appreciated!